# DAX measure (PowerBI) for "filter and extract" certain Temperature ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, dax

I am trying to do Measure to"extract" certain temperature range from my T01 as shown on screenshot, but I have difficulties.. My goal is to "extract" and to show only temperatures that are >=90 and <=120 degrees, only in that interval, so that bandwidth gets thinner and for my assessment. This can be accomplished by adjusting it on Visual level filters directly in PowerBI report, but I wanted to have measure for that, which I can change and use for my needs. What can be good option?

[image: Data Set]

[image: PBI Report]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding a measure, you can also add a column using DAX like `Temperature Filter=AND('Query_Name'[T01]>=90,'Query_Name'[T01]<=120)`. Replace **'Query_Name'** with your query. This will return a TRUE/FALSE as output in the new column.

Then you can use this column in your visual filter or as a slicer and choose TRUE. You can even change the DAX whenever you like and the filter will be update accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, it works also on that way, made my stuff easier. But still I would like to understand it for myself with measures if that is possible. Thank you very much for this help!